# using panoramaGL library in ios5 and running HelloPanorama

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, compatibility, xcode4.3, panorama-control

I've been search around how to setup panoramaGL for a whole day and none of these answers my questions. emm, maybe that's because I am new to ios developing and I start with ios5 with all ARC cool features. I did find a pretty comprehensive guide at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60635/Panorama-360-iPod-Touch-iPhone but it's a little bit out of date to me. I cannot follow this guide in xcode 4.3 with ios 5.0 sdk.

Emm, so here is the question, assuming panoramaGL and helloPanorama works perfectly fine in whatever xcode version and sdk version it is created in. Is there a way , without any code modification, I can import the library and using the api along with my app developed in ios5?  Of course I don't mind some minor modification and I did dive into those code and comment all the retain or release stuff. but wired errors keep popping up. I really need help here.

If it finally turns out to be impossible to reuse it in ios5.0, I will probably need to write the whole thing line by line with my understand of the complicated panorama algorithm...

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems someone is working on another library based on panoramaGL. Works on IOS 5.

See http://code.google.com/p/tk-panorama/

Answer (score 1):

The new version of PanoramaGL 0.1 r2 was released, please check http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/. This version runs on iOS >= 4.x and supports Hotspots.

Please check HelloPanoramaGL example